Did the widows of Israel have a mandatory or voluntary dress code?
We read in Mk 12:41-42(KJV):

And Jesus sat over against the treasury, and beheld how the people cast money into the treasury: and many that were rich cast in much. And there came a certain poor widow, and she threw in two mites, which make a farthing.

There are also other occasions- both in NT and OT- where certain women are identified as widows without their introducing themselves as such. In the foregone days, widows in some societies were mandated to have a dress code, say white in colour, rough in texture and modest in appearance.  It was more of a voluntary practice than of a compulsory requirement .
My question is : According to Bible historians, did the widows of Israel have a mandatory or voluntary dress code ?

An interesting Q. I can only comment re. Jesus. He had no need to go by the appearance of this woman to know that the tiny amount she contributed "was all her living". How could her garments inform him of that? How did he know that she had no money left after her voluntary donation? Due to his divine nature, he could also have known whether she had any children, or whether she had any serious illness, or whatever he desired to know. My own saying is, "A widow's mite is slight, but a widow's mite in the hand of the Almighty is mighty."

Thanks, Anne. I was reading the Verses in the form they had come from Mark's  narrative . Of course, the Evangelist  would have written in retrospect that the lady involved was a widow.  My question is : could a layman tell from the attire of a lady that she was a widow ?
